# How can I fix errors thrown by py2app in python script with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, py2app

I have a python program that uses Pandas and I'm trying to bundle it into a Mac app. In my setup.py file I have:

```
...
OPTIONS = {
    'packages': ['pandas', 'matplotlib', 'numpy']
}
....
```

But when I run

```
python3 setup.py py2app --packages=PIL
```

The app builds, and when is run gives this error:

```
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/craign/Desktop/dist/ranker.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 167, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/craign/Desktop/dist/ranker.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/craign/Desktop/dist/ranker.app/Contents/Resources/ranker.py", line 16, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "pandas/__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "pandas/_libs/__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
SystemError: <method 'load_module' of 'zipimport.zipimporter' objects> returned NULL without setting an error
2020-12-27 13:07:00.376 ranker[97623:8711058] ranker Error
```

Any ideas how to fix? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the file `pandas/_libs/__init__.pyc` line 13, it looks like Pandas is having trouble importing one of its Cython components: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/__init__.py#L13

Comment: 1) Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807762/kivy-application-deployment-using-py2app-on-mac-os-mojave 2) Take a look at https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/305. Looks like py2app contains a fix for @loader_path which is not in the PyPi version yet. Try installing the version from github?

Comment: Thanks, @NickODell wouldn't that also affect the actual Python code as well? The program runs fine, and the version compiled with python3 setup.py py2app -A works as well. It's just when run setup without -A is when the error is thrown while running.

Comment: Not necessarily. py2app might not be bundling the cython files correctly.

Comment: @NickODell I'm learning that I just don't know enough about how Python works under the hood to pull it from Github. It's not like a C++ Make build... I've Googled and StackOverflowed around how-to install py2app from Github, and I'm not seeing how, including in the sparse instructions in Github. Can you point me to how to build, test, and install py2app from Github?

Comment: To install from github, try cloning the repo with git, then run `python setup.py install` within the repo. See https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-from-source for more information.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks super, but sadly after installing from Github, same error.

Comment: Frig. Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Maybe you could strip your project down to the minimum set of dependencies/code that cause the error, and make a post in the py2app issue tracker? I tried to make a Pandas py2app executable, and I couldn't figure it out either...

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade your python to python3.6. This worked for me! I had the same problem!

Comment: I have great sadness downgrading. I totally try to see if I can make it work without it 